# Implementation of t9 dictionary using tries

Tags: c

I want to implement a t9 prediction dictionary(mobile phones) using tries.I also want to save the entered text in a file.How do I do that?? n Where do I store all the words entered?? Im really confused:(.. Plz help..

Comment: Way too vague. Based on this, the only possible answer I have is "by writing code", and "in a string, and then in a file". Reading this should prove helpful: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html Also, if it's homework as I suspect, tag it "homework".

Answer (score 0):

Tries store *Values* associated with *Keys*.  In this case, the Key would be the sequence of keypad keys used to enter the word, and the Value would be the word itself.  You may have multiple words associated with a single key.